# Auto sync images and videos into webservice

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How to auto sync the images and video from the app into the Api Web services.

Do we have any tutorials or source codes on this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple approaches depending upon what you are trying to achieve and what backend you are using.

- If you are using simple API web services, you need to write your own mechanism both on server as well as client side, which will identify records to be synced based on TimeStamp and few other columns in your DB
- If you are open to use other Platforms like Parse.com, they provide in built APIs and libraries to take care of syncing logic
- As you are trying to sync file(Images and Videos), you can also try DropBox, iCloud, or Google Drive. [Here is a link](http://timisted.github.io/TICoreDataSync/ios-tutorial.html) to an article which i found in a quick search which uses CoreData and Dropbox

Let me know if this helps.